# Using phpseclib to connect to a Sonicwall device

Tags: php, ssh

Trying to use phpseclib to replace the SSH2 dll on my server so i can move to php 5.6 and up.  I use SSH to log into Sonicwall firewalls and export configuration files.

Logging in via SSH isnt like remoting to a linux box.  Putty, for instance, asks for a username when you first connect, but the sonicwall ignores that, shows its welcome banner, and then asks for a username and password.

I am able to connect currently using the following code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host);
ssh2_auth_none($connection,$user);
$shell = ssh2_shell($connection,'vt102',null,80,40,SSH2_TERM_UNIT_CHARS);
fwrite($shell, $user."\n");
fwrite($shell, $pass."\n");
// etc
```

I tried the following with phpseclib using the example from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/auth.html#noauth:

```
$ssh = new \Net_SSH2('172.17.1.99');
$ssh->login("admin");
$ssh->read('User:');
$ssh->write('admin');
$ssh->read('Password:');
$ssh->write('password');
```

But something is getting hung up and i get nothing until my execution timeout hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I completely missed the newline after the username and password.